# Another visual puzzle to tuck into

Tags: riddle, word, visual

A *plural* word connects these images:

[image: visual-5key]           [image: visual-WVseal]

[image: visual-auction] [image: visual-ammo]

[image: visual-tête-à-tête]           [image: visual-map]

[image: visual-noexit]     [image: visual-show]

[image: visual-equations]

**What is the word, and what are the connections?**

<sub>*Part of a <kbd>[metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)</kbd> entry: **[I, for one, welcome our new ...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51078/i-for-one-welcome-our-new)***</sub>

Comment: In my opinion people should use more English tag…

Comment: I added the "word" tag which serves some of the same purpose. Rubio, if that was a mistake please accept my apologies and undo it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

partial maybe?

> points

because

> title "tuck" - tuck points or tuck pointing is when you use 2 contrasting colors of brick and mortar
>  1. decimal points or percentage points
>  2. <s>seal points ? - like as in the color of coat of cats West Point(s)? (as per [Silenus's comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50991/another-visual-puzzle-to-tuck-into/51000#comment156321_51000))</s> **edit**: Points, West Virginia (the place) as per Rubio's comment
>  3. selling points?
>  4. bullet points
>  5. conversational/talking points
>  6. the compass points north, or the points of a compass
>  7. points of entry
>  8. points of view
>  9. <s>points of integration? action points or points in time and space (by [Gareth's comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50991/another-visual-puzzle-to-tuck-into#comment156245_50994))?</s> Lagrangian Points

Comment: +1 - This looks pretty promising to me. Nice job! Neither seal points nor points of integration seem very likely though - can you find more convincing explanations for them?

Comment: Although completely unnecessary, Compass points, Entry points, and Viewpoints are valid ways of expressing each, which may fit better as a pattern with your other answers...

Comment: You make excellent points here, @indubitablee, and that pesky last one looks suspiciously like [a likely suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point), but I don't have pencil and paper handy to verify that

Comment: @humn **[Gareth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50991/another-visual-puzzle-to-tuck-into#comment156245_50994)** already saved you the trouble of working it out, methinks.

Comment: (The comments from Gareth and humn share a particularly relevant key word ...)

Comment: The seal clues **West Point**, a town in WV.

Comment: ^ Right idea, wrong place.  25437.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Lol I never would have gotten those 2 on my own (i actually dont really know if theyre right but I'm using the clues you gave me) ><". I was actually considering ditching my answer and pursuing the word "lines" instead

Answer (score 1):

> Seeking 
>  Seeking the key to __
>  Seeking Statehood (Seal has date in which WV became a state)
>  Seeking a bidder
>  Seeking a target (or Self-guided "seeking" bullet)
>  Seeking a conversation
>  North Seeking
>  Seeking Entry
>  Seeking different points of view
>  Seeking a solution

I kinda finagled some of these - just a guess

Comment: Read the very first line of the post proper ;)

Comment: My brain really isn't functioning tody

Answer (score 1):

**Very partial and probably entirely wrong answer**

The best I can find so far -- which I'm about 95% sure is wrong -- is

> EARS

mostly because of the coincidence between

> mountain*eers* (the *montani* in the West Virginia seal's motto) and the old saying that "walls have *ears*". There's an auction*eer* too, but only one of him.

But I don't see any plausible way to link this with anything else. Another thing that's probably just an amusing coincidence is that we have

> an **auction** and the **action** (for a single scalar field in classical field theory). But again I don't see any way to take this further; no obvious reactions, factions, or actins.

Comment: Hmm you can make a lots of connections with ERS or EERS but I'm not sure that counts as a word

Comment: Doesn't each of the final equations represent an action, thus yielding the plural *actions*? I don't know Lagrangian mechanics or field theory or wherever these equations come from, but I thought that there were two actions represented there.

Comment: Nope. The first equation tells you how to compute an action (conventionally denoted S) by taking an integral of the so-called Lagrangian density over all of space and time. The second tells you how to compute a Lagrangian as an integral over space (but not time). That one isn't an action, but its time integral would be.

Comment: No "-eer" type funny business going on here, the word is a proper Scrabble word.  Some of the links are a bit more obscure to keep this from being solved in 10 minutes (one for sure probably deserves a [tag:trivia] and/or [tag:knowledge] tag which I may add) but overall this should be solvable. Keep trying :)

Answer (score -2):

Here's  my answer,  and some reasons why.

Friends, because under 5% of people you meet in life become very good friends, friends will go on a thousand mile trip together over Easter break to West Virginia to see one of the friends' mom and climb around the mountains, at least one of your friends will be related to an auctioneer, friends will enjoy a few rounds of plinking with you, friends will be perfectly happy to talk with you about nothing at all, friends will give you directions when you get lost, friends are always there when you get into something you can't find a way out of, friends will show you different views of the world, and when you are 100% certain the universe is flat, they will go to extreme lengths to provide proof that you are wrong just to make you work harder to prove yourself right, even if you really are wrong.

Friends will also tuck a blanket in around you while you are asleep just because they care.

Comment: In case it needs to be said - um, no, **friends** is not the correct word. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: :) I'll admit I had to look up the scaler field thing to learn about that, but it turned out my instinct was right, that was connected to friends too!  Lol. Since it is giving me negative points though, I recognize that humor is not acceptable here and will delete my answer. I do enjoy all your puzzles though, thank you for creating and sharing them