# A Soupçon of Rebus Recreation

Tags: word, rebus

It's a **rebus puzzle**.  You know what to do.
**What single English word do these symbols represent?**

[image: rebus-old-telephone]

[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-star]
[image: rebus-plus]
[image: rebus-sick-child]

[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-hartman]
[image: rebus-plus]
[image: rebus-bookworm]

[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-scale]

[image: rebus-plus]
[image: rebus-otter]
[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-gold-bar]

[image: rebus-plus]
[image: rebus-moving-van]
[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-old-spice]

[image: rebus-plus]

[image: rebus-youtube-hash]

[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-oil-rig]

[image: rebus-plus]
[image: rebus-spool]
[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-bread-basket]

[image: rebus-plus]

[image: rebus-trypophobia]

[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-ballot]
 
[image: rebus-minus]
[image: rebus-poop-emoji]

<sub>*Part of a <kbd>[metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)</kbd> entry: **[I, for one, welcome our new ...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51078/i-for-one-welcome-our-new)***</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It goes like this:

> PHONE
>  -ONE -> PH
>  +ILL -> PHILL
>  -PHIL -> L
>  +READING -> LREADING
>  -RE -> LADING
>  +OTTER -> LADINGOTTER
>  -INGOT -> LADTER
>  +RYDER -> LADTERRYDER
>  -TERRY -> LADDER
>  +RICKROLL -> LADDERRICKROLL
>  -DERRICK -> LADROLL
>  +SPOOL -> LADROLLSPOOL
>  -ROLLS -> LADPOOL
>  +EYES -> LADPOOLEYES
>  -YES -> LADPOOLE
>  -POO -> LADLE

so our final answer is

> LADLE.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have done it...

> PHONE-ONE+ILL-PHIL+READING-RE+OTTER-INGOT+RYDER-TERRY+RICKROLL-DERRICK+SPOOL-ROLLS+EYES-YES-POO...

Gives us...

> The English Word LADLE
> (meaning a a large long-handled spoon with a cup-shaped bowl, used for serving soup or sauce.)

Comment: Gareth answered this with the correct answer 12 minutes ago...

Comment: How to do it ? . I have joined today itself. @Rubio

Comment: @SwarnabjaBhaumik You use >! in front of your answers to add the spoiler tag - however this puzzle was already solved, adding in yours is redundant.